# how to compare values in the same field?

Tags: arrays, unix, awk

I have this input

```
name   num   value
A     1010232   1
A     1010232   2
A     1010232   3
B     2565214   1
B     2565214   2
B     2565214   3
C     6111111   2
C     6111111   3
.
.
```

O need output like this:

```
the  name C has no "1"  value actually
```

I don't have  any idea about the way to solve it

Comment: More info is needed: how many possible values are there? And above all: what have you tried?

Comment: So you are looking for lines with only two fields?

Comment: how can  i put my qustin in horezental forme

Comment: yes for lines with only two fields

Comment: Here you go `awk 'BEGIN{print "the name C has no 1 value actually"}'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat file                                                                    
name   num   value
A     1010232   1
A     1010232   2
A     1010232   3
B     2565214   1
B     2565214   2
B     2565214   3
C     6111111   2
C     6111111   3

$ awk '
NR>1 { seen[$1,$3]++; names[$1]; vals[$3] }
END {
    for (name in names)
        for (val in vals)
            if (!seen[name,val])
                printf "the name %s has no \"%s\" value actually\n", name, val
}
' file
the name C has no "1" value actually
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
awk -f chk.awk input.txt
```

where `chk.awk` is:

```
{
    a[$1,$3]++
}

END {
    if (!("C","1") in a)
        print "the name C has no \"1\" value"
}
```